# Emacs - Min chars for auto completion

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm using Emacs to write Java code (but I noticed this happens for other languages as well), and I'm having an issue with the completion. Say I want to import a library:

```
import java.|
```

Where `|` is the cursor. If I invoke the auto completion, it won't show anything.

```
import java.u|
```

In the case above, if I invoke auto completion, it works, showing every candidate starting with `u`.
Is it possible to change this behavior of needing to type the first letter to see the results? It would also be nice to do that for other languages as well.

I read the auto-complete documentation, also tried to study and change the code, but as I'm not familiar with lisp, didn't have any success.

Comment: What backend are you using? Smart package completion is not supported by emacs or auto-complete alone, what other packages are you using?

Comment: @JordonBiondo I'm using eclim for the java auto completion. But as I said, this happens in other languages as well. Type `(` in lisp and trigger auto completion. It doesn't come up. but type `(d` and trigger auto completion again. Now it does